# How to set a local variable when a certain file is visited

Tags: variables

EDIT: Changed "load" to "visit"

I want to set a variable when a specific file is visited, for example "package.json". Note I don't want to set a variable when any json file is visited, only for "package.json". What is the easiest way to achieve this.

I guess it can be done with a hook to json-mode that calls a function that sets the variable, but was wondering if there is a more idiomatic solution.

I'm looking for something similar to how it is defined in [.dir-locals.el](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Directory-Variables.html): `("package.json" . ((nil . ((my-var . "value"))))))`, but something defined in my init.el for all directories.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: @Drew my bad, at first I didn't know what tag to use so I put elisp as a placeholder, then searched and added "variables" and forgot to remove the elisp tag placeholder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use either of:

```el
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("/package\\.json\\'" . package-json-mode))

(define-derived-mode package-json-mode json-mode "package.json"
  "Major mode for editing package.json files."
  (setq-local VARNAME VALUE))
```

or:

```el
(add-hook 'json-mode-hook 'my-json-mode-hook)

(defun my-json-mode-hook ()
  "Used in `json-mode-hook'."
  (when (equal (file-name-nondirectory (buffer-file-name)) "package.json")
    (setq-local VARNAME VALUE)))
```

You could also use `find-file-hook` instead of `json-mode-hook`,
but I'd prefer the major mode hook to that.

With `auto-mode-alist` you might `(require 'json-mode)` first to ensure that its more generic `.json` pattern doesn't get added *after* (and hence take precedence over) your `package.json` pattern; but if you've installed json-mode via the package manager and its autoloads have been loaded ahead of your custom code, you should be safe to ignore that issue.

Comment: I'm concerned about using new major mode, lets say there's a major mode alist with only json-mode in it, would it be picked up for package-json-mode or not? specifically this https://github.com/radian-software/apheleia/blob/23c8b7d1ca3d855b38b8fe8bee760fa1234b6143/apheleia-formatters.el#L227-L288

Comment: small correction for your second solution, instead of `file-name-base` it should be `file-name-nondirectory` https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/File-Name-Components.html#index-file_002dname_002dnondirectory

Comment: As long as the code checking the major mode is well-written it will be using `derived-mode-p` to test (if there's no specific reason not to do so), in which case anything already targeting `json-mode` will automatically recognise your derived mode too.  (This is one of the intentions behind derived modes.)  Situations where they are treated differently are certainly possible, but *should* be rare.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't too clear to me, as you speak of both "loading" a file and "visiting" a file, which are two different things. I'm assuming you want to set a variable after a file named "package.json" has been loaded.

```lisp
(with-eval-after-load "package.json"
 (setq my-var  "value")
 ;; .. whatever else you want to do
 )
```

`C-h f with-eval-after-load`:

> **`with-eval-after-load`** is a Lisp macro in `subr.el`.
>
> `(with-eval-after-load FILE &rest BODY)`
>
> Execute `BODY` after `FILE` is loaded.
>
> `FILE` is normally a feature name, but it can also be a file name,
> in case that file does not provide any feature.  See `eval-after-load`
> for more details about the different forms of `FILE` and their semantics.

See also the Elisp manual, node [Hooks for Loading](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Hooks-for-Loading.html).

Comment: I imagine it's the opposite, and they want to set a buffer-local var when visiting the file.  Loading a JSON file wouldn't make sense to me.

Comment: @phils: Maybe so. but a library named `package.json.el` would make sense. That was my assumption. But the question isn't clear...

Comment: sorry for being unclear, I meant visiting a file